# Can we integrate Resharper-cli with TFS

Tags: tfs, resharper

I am trying to integrate resharper with TFS build .Can anybody let me know if it is possible to integrate resharper-cli with TFS

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want the build to refactor code? Normally I would expect code to be refactored by developers and then checked in. Are you intending for the code refactored by the build to be checked in to source control?

Comment: @JamesReed ReSharper is not only refactorings but a lot of useful code analyses too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the free new [Resharper Command line tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html). It has Duplicate Analysis and Code Analysis that you can run from the command line and probably integrate with TFS.

Comment: yes i have tried it but it generates a xml file , but currently i dont see any report generator to read this xml file and display the results in html or console format

Comment: Probably not too difficult to write your own.