# How to automate Re-sharper Rules on build Machine?

Tags: resharper, build-automation

We want to automate Re-sharper rules on build machine, We have around 20 Resharper rules mostly editor level changes like indentation etc. When we check in code we want Re-sharper to analyze code and do modifications automatically as per the rules. Please provide approach how we can do it ? We use TFS for source control and source code is C++ MFC and C#.
       Need to method to change code automatically as per resharper rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we integrate Resharper-cli with TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570804/can-we-integrate-resharper-cli-with-tfs)

Comment: Need method to change code automatically according to configured Resharper rules

Comment: What you could do is write a unit test that _only runs on the build server_ - create a local workspace, run the analysis, check out the changed files, and check them in again: it's not trivial, but it can be done, and the TFS API is well documented. So when you check in, the build runs the tests, which format the code. (I should say though that I personally think this is the wrong way to do things. The code that gets checked in should be the code that gets saved, if you want it to be formatted a certain way then make your developers do that, it's just CTRL-E CTRL-C after all (IIRC))